# Best way to redraw NSView 60 times per second?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, core-graphics, nsview

I have a view in my OS X app that I need to fully redraw (ideally) 60 times per second. I'm currently using Core Graphics in the NSView draw function for the drawing like so:

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)

    // Drawing code here.
    let context = NSGraphicsContext.current!.cgContext
    // Core Graphics drawing calls using context
}
```

And then, in the view controller viewDidAppear() I schedule a timer to force the view to redraw (roughly) 60 times per second, which, while working, is certainly a terrible way to achieve the desired result.

```
//ViewController.swift
override func viewDidAppear() {
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.016, target: self, selector: #selector(redrawView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    super.viewDidAppear()
}

@objc func redrawView() {
    let v = view as! View
    v.redraw()
}

//View.swift
class View: NSView {
    func redraw() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.setNeedsDisplay(self.frame) //this is because drawing calls apparently need to be in the main thread
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this (I'm sure there is)? From my (remarkably lacking) knowledge of NSView and its drawing model, it doesn't seem that NSView was made with constant redrawing like this in mind.

I'm not particular about using NSView, but I would very much like to use Core Graphics (Metal is not an option, because I'm already using it heavily for GPGPU stuff).

Any advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: You should only redraw if something has changed in a way that requires redrawing, and even then, if you're really trying to optimize performance, you'll want to only redraw the rect that has changed (the "dirty" rect). Redrawing 60 times a second just "for the sake of it" is kind of ... pointless.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! My idea is, finally, to only redraw when something changed. It's just that in this particular case, in every 60th of a second, it is more common that a change has taken place than not (ie. it's common to have to redraw 60 times a second), so I'd like to do this the most effective, "in sync with display refresh"-way as possible. Also, I do realise redrawing only the "dirty" rect is the way to go, and always do so whenever possible. It just so happens that the dirty rect in this particular case is always the entire view.

Comment: You should check out https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling CADisplayLink might be just what I needed, but still haven't looked very deeply into it. Will do so!

Comment: @Alexander The question asks about NSView, which is on macOS. CADisplayLink is not available on macOS.

Comment: @DannyNiu It has `CVDisplayLink`. Is it similar?

Comment: @Alexander Yes, it's similar. I've used `CVDisplayLink` in [my app](https://github.com/dannyniu/Studio-Media-Player) for the purpose this Q asked for. I've linked to it so that OP can reference it for use in his app.